# how i can change label password in django froms?

Tags: python, django

i need change label (  password = forms.PasswordInput() ) in created form in django .

i tried this :

```
 from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='نام و نام خوانوادگی', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='ایمیل')
    password1 = forms.PasswordInput(label='پسورد')
    number = forms.IntegerField(label='شماره همراه')



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name' , 'email' ,  'number','password1']
```

but it dont work and have error :
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'

Comment: `PasswordInput` is a widget, not a form field. So your way of defining the password field is wrong. Show us your entire form. Or if you're using a model form, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields), where you'll find how to override the `labels` on a model form.

Comment: @dirkgroten i dont use model . i use forms.py and inherit class from UserCreation Class

Comment: "use forms.py" what does that mean? I said "model form" not "model". show us forms.py

Comment: please edit your question, don't post code in comments. It's not possible to read.

Comment: use the "edit" button below the question to add your code to the question.

Comment: @dirkgrotenok . i edited post , please help me

Comment: @dirkgroten ok , lets see what i can do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inheriting from `UserCreationForm`, which is a `ModelForm`, as I mentioned in the comments. If you look at the source code of `UserCreationForm`, you'll see that `password1` is defined as a `forms.CharField` and that it's not coming from the model.

Replace your password field like this:

```
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label="پسورد",
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
```

Also, remove "password1" from the `fields` list. It's not a field from the user model.

Comment: i got :   NameError: name 'password_validation' is not defined

Comment: you need to import it. `from django.contrib.auth import password_validation`

Comment: its work , but i have question , how i can hide deatils under the password field ? such as password must be 8 character ?

Comment: that's the help_text. Remove it then.